# company-mode doesn't complete preprocessor syntax

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I've followed the  [Tuhdo's](https://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html) tutorial, but I've got a problem with company-mode: it seems it doesn't auto complete *preprocessor* reserved words, as displayed in these two images no candidates are found:
[image: include]
[image: define]

But, on the contrary, this image shows that company mode is active and working:
[image: stdio]

What's wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here you go the list of the active backends: `(company-c-headers company-bbdb company-nxml company-css company-eclim company-semantic company-clang company-xcode company-cmake company-capf company-files (company-dabbrev-code company-gtags company-etags company-keywords) company-oddmuse company-dabbrev)`

Answer (score 0):

hi problem same for me

Basically company-keywords does not include preprocessor directives.

So I've just wrote this backend that is triggered when you type #+ a letter.

https://github.com/fredericfrances/company-c-preprocessor

Installation and setup is pretty easy, I did'nt create melpa package yet.

(require 'company-c-preprocessor)
(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-c-preprocessor)